# Set the GUID value of VSTO AddIn

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I don't understand how i can set the GUID value of a VSTO AddIn. In EventViewer i see Empty GUID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}.

[image]

I've tried using the Guid and ProgId attributes on the ThisAddIn class, but that doesn't help. Can you please tell me how to change the GUID.

Answer (score 0):

That GUID is the COM GUID. It does not matter in a VSTO addin since VSTO loads your addin, not Outlook directly.

Comment: How i can change COM GUID to fix this display in EventViewer?

Comment: Why do you need to? Isn't addin name unique enough?

Answer (score 0):

`Guid` (Globally unique identifier) is used to identify your component by outside world. When you write a project which is going to be used as COM (Component Object Model) you will have to give a unique name. For this reason you need to apply `GUID` attribute.

For VSTO add-ins you need to apply the `Guid` attribute to the assembly, not the add-in class like in case of other COM add-ins you could do that. For example, if you try to create a new VSTO add-in and open the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file (for C# projects) you may find the following entry there:

```
// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("74776e40-0ee0-412c-b7aa-e39838a741c1")]
```

That makes sense only if you set the `ComVisible` to true. By default, VSTO doesn't use `ProgID` and `Guid` attributes for loading add-ins. Instead, the `VSTOLoader` is used for loading managed add-in assemblies without relying on the COM technology, so assemblies are not registered  for the COM interop.